# How to select the inner query's result as an output

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the inner query's column as output in the select statement? Here the `lang` in `users` table needs to be returned by the select statement. Is it possible with this query?

```
SELECT ID, LANG  -- THIS LANG IS NOT WORKING
INTO V_TRAVEL_ID, V_LANG
FROM TRAVEL_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID = (SELECT MYID, LANG -- this LANG column needs to be returned from the query
                 FROM USERS
                 WHERE CONTACT_ID = V_CONTACT_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your query is phrased does allow you to filter the travels per user contact, but you can't access the details of the concerned user - because the main query only selects from the travels table.

Probably you want a `join` instead; this lets you filter the dataset *and* makes columns of both tables available for `select`:

```
SELECT t.id, u.lang
INTO v_travel_id, v_lang
FROM travel_table t
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE u.contact_id = v_contact_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `users` table will match a single row for each row in the `travel_table` then:

```sql
SELECT t.ID,
       u.LANG
INTO   V_TRAVEL_ID,
       V_LANG
FROM   TRAVEL_TABLE t
       INNER JOIN USERS u
       ON u.MYID = t.USER_ID
WHERE  u.CONTACT_ID = V_CONTACT_ID;
```

If the `users` table could match multiple rows and you want to match the behaviour of the `IN` filter and only match one of them then, from Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and get the first match only:

```sql
SELECT t.ID,
       u.LANG
INTO   V_TRAVEL_ID,
       V_LANG
FROM   TRAVEL_TABLE t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT u.LANG
         FROM   USERS u
         WHERE  u.CONTACT_ID = V_CONTACT_ID                                                 
         AND    u.MYID       = t.USER_ID
         -- ORDER BY something
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) u;
```

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you want to use subquery instead of inner join you then `cross apply` / `cross join lateral` should do the trick. `, lateral` is the shortest one. :)

```
select * from travel_table
```

either

```
cross apply (select * from t2 users
where contact_id = v_contact_id and user_id = myid)
```

or

```
cross join lateral (select * from users
where contact_id = v_contact_id and user_id = myid)
```

or

```
, lateral (select * from t2 users
where contact_id = v_contact_id and user_id = myid)
```

The main difference between 3 above queries and the original one though is that original one can return only 0 or 1 rows while any of the above can return any number of matching rows.

Technically, above queries are equivalent to (pay attention to `any` keyword)

```
select *
  from travel_table
 where user_id = any (select myid from users where contact_id = v_contact_id);
```